# Meaning of "Dienstag vergangener Woche"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

> Dienstag vergangener Woche in Monaco.

Is that the same as *Letzten Dienstag*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost:

> Am Dienstag vergangener Woche

means `on the Thursday of last week`. While

> am letzten Dienstag

means `last Thursday.` They're very similar but not the same.

Comment: Right, except for Tuesday instead of Thursday.

Answer (score 4):

They mean the same on Mondays and Tuesdays but not so on the other days.

Comment: To clarify: on a Wednesday, it means 8 days ago. On a Monday it means 6 days ago.

Answer (score 2):

*Dienstag vergangener Woche* is the same as *Dienstag letzter Woche*

> Last week's tuesday

both should **not** be confused with *Letzten Dienstag*

> Last tuesday

Pay attention, that a German week starts on Monday, not Sunday. So a sentence like *Sunday last week* might refer to *yesterday* if said no a Monday.